# to creating custom toolbar in magento get error Call to a member function setCurPage() on a non-object

Tags: toolbar

I display All Manufacturer with image with slider on Home page as block. there i put the View All link, on clicking that link its display all the manufacurer in new pahe as category page.
i created manufacturer.php as under

```
<?php
class Bc_Manufacturer_Block_Manufacturerpage extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

public function getManufacturer()     
{ 
    if (!$this->hasData('manufacturer')) {
        $this->setData('manufacturer', Mage::registry('manufacturer'));
    }
    return $this->getData('manufacturer');

   }
public function getToolbarHtml() {

    $this->setToolbar($this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar', 'Toolbar'));

    $toolbar = $this->getToolbar();

    $toolbar->enableExpanded();

    $toolbar->setAvailableOrders(array(

            'ordered_qty' => $this->__('Position'),

            'name' => $this->__('Name'),

            'price' => $this->__('Price')

        ))

        ->setDefaultDirection('desc')

        ->setCollection($this->_productCollection);


    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'Pager');

    $pager->setCollection($this->_productCollection);

    $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);

    return $toolbar->_toHtml();

}

}
```

also call the getToolbarHtml() function in the manufacurerpage.phtml file as under
    
    
        getToolbarHtml() ?>

```
    <div class="grid-type-full">
        <?php foreach($maufacturers as $manufacturer): ?>
            <?php if(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')->setAttribute(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product',"manufacturer")))->getOptionText($manufacturer->getMenufecturerName())): ?>

                <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
                    <ul class="products-grid">
                <?php endif ?>
                        <li style="position: relative; float: left; display: inline-block; " class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=".$manufacturer->getMenufecturerName() ?>">
                                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setmanufacturerimage($manufacturer->getFilename())->setlegend($manufacturer->getLegend())->setListPageFlag(1)->setTemplate('manufacturer/manufacturer_resize.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
                                <div class="manufacturer-name">
                                    <?php echo Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')->setAttribute(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product',"manufacturer")))->getOptionText($manufacturer->getMenufecturerName()) ?>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                 <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 && $i!=count($maufacturers)): ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    </div>

<div class="toolbar-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
```

after run this i got the error as under

Fatal error: Call to a member function setCurPage() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\jumbostore\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php on line 225

any one have solution for this please help me...

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a really late response , I had faced similar issue and found out that the `setCollection()`
was not getting the Product Collection.

You can find the Code at Your path `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php` at around line no 221.

```
 <?php   
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage()); //*****HERE

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
    return $this;
}
?>
```

Please try checking whether your function is getting the Collection or not.
Hope this is some help!!!